# How to scroll NSScrollView with no animation?

Tags: cocoa, appkit, nsscrollview

When I scroll a `NSScrollView` using `scrollToVisible` or `scroll(_:)` method, I see they are slightly animated.

How to eliminate these animations?

Answer (score 1):

Just adjust clip view's bounding origin like this.

```
(superview as! NSClipView).bounds.origin = f.origin
```

This brings absolutely no animation, and you gonna see no stuttering.

[Here's another sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19399242/soft-scroll-animation-nsscrollview-scrolltopoint) how other people are using it.